# majority element . it would be very helpful if someone could point out the fault

Tags: c

I have provided only for an array of size 6. the first element is copied into a variable the variable is matched with other elements of the array

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[6],i,j,k,count=0;
    printf("enter the nos");
    for(i=0;i<=5;i++)         //loop to accept values from the user
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<=5;i++)
    {
    arr[i]=j;             //the 1st element is assigned to j
        for(k=0;k<=5;k++)
        {
            if(arr[k]==j)
            {
                count++;  //whenever the required element is found in the array count is increased
            }
        }
        if(count>=3)
        {
            printf("the majority elt is %d",j);
        }
        else
        {
            count=0;  //if above conditions dont satisfy the count is again set to 0
        }  
    //the inner loop after completing its iterations gives control to the outer loop
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem with the code you show? What is your question? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to assigned the an element to `j` as you meant in your comment:

> // the 1st element is assigned to j

you have to write it like this: `j = arr[i];`

Apart from this you can stop searching if you found the majority. Adapt your code like this:

```
for(i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
   j = arr[i];
   for(k=0;k<=5;k++)
   {
       if(arr[k]==j)
           count++;  //whenever the required element is found in the array count is increased
   }
   if(count>=3)
   {
       printf("the majority elt is %d",j); 
       break; // <- you are finished
   }
   else
     count = 0;
}
```

Comment: the problem is that if i input 1 2 1 3 1 3

Comment: whereas if all the ones are consecutive the output is correct

Comment: the output for the input 121313 is the majority element is 1 the majority element is 2 and so on

Comment: i expected it to be 1

Comment: pls can u suggest any books or sites where i could brush up my coding skills